# Create a computer login screen VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, windows-xp-sp3

I would like to create a VB.net program that will prompt a user before it shows them their desktop for a password. If the password is correct it will log in. If incorrect, after a couple of tries the compuer will shut down. The only problem is starting the program without showing any icons or the taskbar. I haven't tried the startup folder in the start menu because wouldn't that show the desktop first? Also I would like it to load *before* the desktop loads (and then continue to load the desktop after logging in) so you can't close it with task manager or accidentally minimize the form (with the Windows Key + D).

Thank you.

P.S. I do *not* care about actual security it is just a way to see who's logging on. Also the people will be logging on to the same Windows account... it's faster than switching users.

(I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express.)

Comment: I don't think you will have much luck with this. If you make a login screen how are you going to ensure the user re-runs your login program when they are done?  I'd just use the built-in user management stuff and upgrade the computer to be faster. Your users will have a better, more secure experience as well!

Comment: Thank you Michael for your comment. I am going to have my program appear when the screensaver starts. (I have that figured out already.) I just need a way to start the program early enough to make the user login. What my program is going to do is basicly just change the desktop and screensaver. I am going to try using the Startup folder in Start sometime...

Comment: Note: I want to avoid creating different Windows accounts because that slowed down my computer (because we used the switch user and that takes up a ton of RAM). I do have a OK computer - 2 gigabyte RAM (and OK proccesser) it's just we have a lot of Startup things running so that prevents things from starting instantly. (Norton, updaters, Skype, they're all necessary for us). I will not upgrade my computer because of economical reasons and because I don't own the computer I'm creating this software for.

Comment: If you log off instead of using Switch Users then you'll find it doesn't cost the extra RAM.  "Switch Users" leaves everyone logged on at the same time.  I'm not sure I understand the value of adding a fake password screen to a machine: `CTRL-ALT-DELETE` will invariably get around it...

Comment: Thank you Dan for your reply. As I said it is just for a wallpaper and screensaver - I might even have just a button for each user - I just need a quick way to start my program. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stop `explorer.exe` from opening temporarily by replacing it with your start-up program in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

So you change `Shell = Explorer.exe` to `Shell = C:\path\to\Myapplication.exe`.

More details can be found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx) (article actually focuses XP Embedded but should work the same way in a regular installation).

What this does is, `explorer.exe` loads the desktop and the taskbar. Windows launches the `.exe` file that is in the registry value we edited and loads the desktop and taskbar. By replacing `explorer.exe` with your program, it launches your program insted.

The desktop will load normally after your application launches `explorer.exe`. (Thanks to Matt for confirming that works.) `Process.Start("explorer.exe")` will launch `explorer.exe` and load your desktop.

If you are not putting your application in the Windows directory or adding it to the Path variable, you need to fully qualify the location (write the full location like above).

Comment: The desktop will load normally after launching explorer.exe.

Comment: Explorer is responsible for the task bar and desktop icons; without it you won't see those.  It's possible for a shell replacement to launch Explorer itself, though I can't imagine this is a sensible idea if the app you're using is *actually* a shell...

Comment: Right, launching explorer from the shell replacement application was what I had in mind. It's the only reliable I can think of to prevent the desktop from loading before the own application as the poster requested. If it makes much sense I'll leave for him to decide :)

Comment: Thank you Paul for your reply. I think that is a great idea to stop explore.exe to stop loading and then load it when ready. I am trying your answer and while on MSDN's website (the page that you listed above) I got kinda confused. Would I change the Explore.exe to my Myapplication.exe and then launch Explore.exe when I want the desktop to load? Also, how to I launch Explore.exe withing my application? Should I create a shortcut and then find out how to launch within? I really apreciate all of your help and would very much apreciate a little more help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added some text to the answer, hope it helps you.

Comment: @Paul Thanks again. I have one more question. Don't I have to have to register Myapplication.exe in the registry to be able to launch Myapplication.exe where exlplore.exe is currently? Or should I just put the path of my program? (I don't know if you can do that in the registry. I have never edited the registry without a guide online but I know well how to use the Registry Editor.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good point, if you are not putting your application in the Windows directory or add it to the Path variable you need to fully qualify the location.

Answer (score 2):

Programs can be started via the registry by adding entries to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Note that you should **not** be storing passwords in plain text. Even if you don't care about actual security your users should care as many people use the same passwords for multiple things.

And there are plenty of ways to bypass this type of program...

Comment: Worth noting that this key exists under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` - the latter will run for every user.

Comment: Thank you Michael for replying. For security, I might even have just a button for each user - I just need a quick way to start my program. I will try your answer and Paul's answer and if one works I'll get back to you guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set shell in command line : REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon /v Shell /t REG_SZ /d  /f